# Can TCP be used like UDP by simply not sending ACK?

Tags: routing, tcp

Assuming both client & server cooperated, could you emulate the functionality of UDP by not sending ACK packets, and not sending retransmissions? Or would most routers somehow bork the process if ACK packets aren't included?

Comment: This wouldn't emulate any of the functionality of UDP as far as I can tell. It wouldn't be connectionless. It wouldn't eliminate all the TCP stuff UDP doesn't want like slow start, exponential backoff, and so on. It wouldn't give you a datagram service.

Comment: This sounds to me like a possible [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)..

Comment: @GregL no, I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

The routers along the way wouldn't care about your use of TCP or UDP (except for access lists). They route based on Data-link and Network level protocols.

Comment: Including NAT routers?

Comment: NAT is a protocol for translating IP addresses between networks. It will not act based on the content of the TCP dataflow, just the IP address and protocol.